# Meteor cordova upload image from gallery?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I am trying to upload a file from the gallery of a device using an image picker plugin for cordova which returns the images location on the device. When I try to access the image on the phone I receive

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
file:///Users/camron/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F762F636-5357-4A67-904D-10009737BAE6/data/Containers/Data/Application/573D203D-3C34-4451-90CD-6E469CFF4C0F/tmp/cdv_photo_022.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//after adding mdg:camera package

var cameraOptions = {  
    quality: 80,
    correctOrientation: true,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}

MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function(error, localData){
    // do stuff
})
```

Comment: I was using this and it was working but I don't know why even with quality 100 this method reduces the images quality. Explained here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mdg-camera-image-quality/19410/2

Comment: I used the same method but got a reference error : 'camera is not defined'. I am running the app on my mobile firefox browser.